# Test security with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I confused with configuration for unit test:

This's my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
public class MyTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private MyController myController;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                    .standaloneSetup(myController)
                    .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
                    .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {

    }

    @Configuration
    static class Config {
        @Bean
        MyController myController() {
            return new MyController();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: springSecurityFilterChain cannot be
>   null. Ensure a Bean with the name springSecurityFilterChain
>   implementing Filter is present or inject the Filter to be used.

How to configure it properly?

Comment: did you find a solution?